# Angular2 application with NodeJS not loading everything

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm experimenting with Angular2 and, with the quick start guide on their official documentation, I'm definitely up and running. However, if I want to do any APIs on the server or host it on the cloud it seems I'll need to use Node. I think I have everything set correctly in the `server.js` file, yet when I run it it seems like it's not loading everything from SystemJS and I get the following errors:

[image: Angular2 errors]

Here is the Node code:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();

var System = require('systemjs');

// loads './app.js' from the current directory
System.import('app').then(function(m) {
  console.log(m);
});

// Config
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));
app.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('MEAN app listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing to include in the Node side that gets included when running `lite-server` from `npm start` that is included from the Angular2 quick start guide.

Answer (score 0):

When you are telling express where to look for the static files, you have to include where your js files will be as well.

For example, in one of my projects I have it like so

```
app.use('/css', express.static(path.resolve(appPath, 'css')));
app.use('/lib/css', express.static(path.resolve(appPath + '/lib', 'css')));
app.use('/lib/js', express.static(path.resolve(appPath + '/lib', 'js')));
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.resolve(appPath, 'assets')));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(path.resolve(appPath, 'node_modules')));
app.use('/app', express.static(path.resolve(appPath, 'app')));
```

I believe that might be your issue or hopefully set you in the right path.

Comment: Thanks! I added the `styles` and `node_modules` like above, but still seem to be getting the errors. Does SystemJS need to be initialized by express, as well?